# Using awk to count number of records

Tags: awk

I want to count all the records in a table through awk but NR prints record nos of all records not the total count. I even tried:

```
NF==4,count++{print count}
```

But its not working properly
 How can I do it through awk?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Please show a sample of your file and what you want to do with it (show the desired output ) next time. Just guessing what you want,

```
awk 'NF==4{count++} END {print count}' file
```

the total number of records is indicated by NR.

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file1 file2
```

the total number of records currently is denoted by FNR.

```
awk 'END{print FNR}' file
```

Comment: +1 Your last command prints the number of records in the last file of a group of files (or only file for one file). I would use `NR` so the results aren't potentially confusing. If you want per-file counts: `awk 'FILENAME != prevfn {print prevfn, prevc} {prevfn = FILENAME; prevc = FNR} END {print prevfn, prevc}' file*`

Answer (score 18):

I guess you mean total number of lines. In general, you should use `wc -l <filename>` for this.
If you want to do this using awk, use

```
awk '{print NR}' | tail -1
```

If you only want to use awk, do

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{i++;}END{print i}' <filename>
```

Comment: `wc -l [file]` displays number of newlines, not number of lines. It will report a number a bit smaller than actual number of lines. @kurumi is right.

Comment: @Nikos: What is the difference between the "number of newlines" and the "number of lines"? Unless I'm mistaken, in POSIX a "line" is defined as a string of text followed by a newline character, so these should be the same unless your file is malformed and missing the last newline.

Comment: @KeyCode `NR` in awk is the number of records, which by default is delimited by a newline character, but can be set to be something else. So if `RS` is set to something else, then `wc -l` will not be same as `NR`.

Answer (score -1):

grep -c  gives the count of matching records