# knowing number of lines via awk in one line

Tags: bash, awk

I use this simple script to count number of lines on awk:

```
BEGIN{ 
count=0
}

{
count++;
}

END
{

}
```

But is there any shorter way? For example, just one line to use on my bash file. I do not like that script on one separate file. I am looking for just one command to use on termial.

Comment: possible solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114586/using-awk-to-count-no-of-records

Comment: Why not just use `wc -l` instead of `awk`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely How I can put that in to a varable ?

Comment: @JonathanWakely a= wc -l myFile is get me error. How I can define a please

Comment: `a=\`wc -l file\`` or `a=$(wc -l file)`

Comment: if you don't know that, how were you planning to use the `awk` script?!

Comment: @EdMorton +1000 for < on your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try that :

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file
```

Comment: +1. this wouldn't work with several files though

Comment: is NR stand for number of row?

Comment: @alex no, it stands for the total number of lines processed so far

Comment: @alex no, it stands for the total Number of Records processed so far across all input files. Theres another variable `FNR` for within the currently open file.